# Is it possible to slice keys in h5py using python 3, without forming a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

I am using h5py to read in data from an HDF5 file, and have found that code which worked using Python 2 does not work using Python 3.  The file is formatted such that 2D frames of data are present as distinct datasets, which I want to read into a 3D array.  The file structure looks like this:

```
file.h5
 |- groupname (group)
     |- frame1 (dataset)
     |- frame2 (dataset)
   ...
```

To read the frames into a 3D array, I have to access the first dataset to get its shape and type information.  Because I don't actually know the *exact* name for each frame, the code I had been using to access the first frame looked like this:

```
import h5py

fid = h5py.File('file.h5', 'r')
datagroup = fid['groupname']
dataset0 = datagroup[datagroup.keys()[0]]
```

However, the [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html) for h5py says

> "When using h5py from Python 3, the keys(), values() and items() methods will return view-like objects instead of lists."

The view objects support iteration but not slicing.  So to avoid an error I had to change that line to the following:

```
dataset0 = datagroup[ [k for k in datagroup.keys()][0] ]
```

which artificially constructs a temporary list and then grabs its first element.  To me this looks awful.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Slightly better: `datagroup[list(datagroup.keys())][0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` supports returning an iterator but is not directly iterable. That leads to the following:

```
dataset0 = datagroup[next(iter(datagroup))]
```

Comment: There must be something different about the internal implementation, because if I do this I get `TypeError: 'KeyView' object is not an iterator` ... which is odd since the documentation explicitly says the view-like objects 'support iteration'. Hmm. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try omitting the `keys()` method call, since iterating over a `Group` should yield names.

Comment: I just closed out of the relevant computer for the day, but I'll give that a shot tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Nope, no dice - `next(datagroup)` causes another `TypeError: 'Group' object is not an iterator`. Argh.

Comment: Okay, try `next(iter(datagroup))` then.

Comment: Yes!  That worked.  Thank you very much, that is much cleaner.